# How to handle a POST method that also has a parameter of unknown type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am coding to handle a Facebook callback. Facebook calls the same Url with POST but with different object types.  I am not ready to handle all the parameter types, so I tried the following:

```
public void Post([FromBody]class1 webhook1)
{  // for object1 
}

public void Post([FromBody]class2 webhook2)
{  // for object12
}

public async Task Post()
{
    string rawData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log(rawData);
}
```

However, I get this exception:

```
"Multiple actions were found that match the request ...
```

Is there a way to allow a fallback option for parameter types I am not ready to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overloading based on the type of parameter is not supported for "web" routing methods

Use route attribute:

```
[Route("webhook1")]
public void Post([FromBody]class1 webhook1) {}

[Route("webhook2")]
public void Post([FromBody]class2 webhook2) {}
```

Or if you don't want client side to know about different parameter's types,
then make one "web" method where you read raw data from the body of request,
detect a type of data and call correspondent method to handle it

Comment: Unfortunately my classes are complex objects and the data is coming in as `application/json`.  I guess I have to get the raw body and try casting to each class one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [attribute based routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) instead as this gives you a lot more flexibility. Web api donot support standard routing methods well.
It should be something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/example")]
public ExampleController : ApiController{

 [Route("postwebhook1")]
 public void Post([FromBody]class1 webhook1)
 {  // for object1 
 }
 [Route("postwebhook2")]
 public void Post([FromBody]class2 webhook2)
 {  // for object12
 }
 [Route("post")]
 public async Task Post()
 {
  string rawData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  log(rawData);
 }
}
```